# Stop an element moving with padding on hover

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a cool css3 effect where by when you hover over an image a border comes out from the middle of the image slowly. To do so I have a transparent border and then show the border and apply padding on hover, but when I add the padding it moves the image. Is there a way to keep the image from moving and still have the padding added on hover?

```
#dev:hover{
    border:solid 3px #76c2af;
    padding:10px;
}


img{
    position: absolute;
    left:64%;
    margin-left:-128px;
    border:solid 3px transparent;
    border-radius: 80px;
    transition-duration: 1s;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 1s; /* Safari */
}
```

Example - http://jsfiddle.net/kqWZZ/1/

Answer (score 3):

You need to displace the padding added on hover.

It seems as though the best approach is to add a margin initially and then remove it on hover.

[**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/JoshC/rzb47/)

```
#dev {
    margin:10px;
}

#dev:hover{
    border:solid 3px #76c2af;
    padding:10px;
    margin:0;
}
```

This essentially displaces the `10px` of padding.

For positioning purposes, I changed `left:64%` to `left:33%`.

Comment: That is a useful fix but it kinda shakes on hover not sure if that's just me on firefox?

Comment: @user2598957 Fixed. Is that what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

You also add a padding on hover, which moves the image. So either add the padding also to the image without hover, or dont add any padding at all.

Comment: I want the padding on hover, because thats the whole point of the effect, have a re-read of the question

Answer (score 0):

Why not transfer the padding attribute on the image itself but not on its hovering state?

I edited your fiddle. Check it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/kqWZZ/1/)

```
img{
   padding:10px;
   ....
}
```