# CSS: Adding border to button on hover. How avoiding a shifting of the following elements?

Tags: html, css

My idea is to add a colored border to the submit button when the user hovers it.

```css
body div:first-child {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  background-color: #dedede;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-left: 300px;
  width: 120px;
  height: 80px;
  border-radius: 8px;
}

button {
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}

button:hover {
  border: 6px solid crimson;
  font-weight: 800;
  background-color: white;
  color: crimson;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <button>SUBMIT</button>
  <div>Please notice that ...</div>
</div>
```

But the immediately following text then becomes shifted downwards.

How can I get rid of these "Jumping" text while simultaneously having the border?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add "margin" attributes to your "button" CSS like so:

```
button {
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  margin: 4px 0;
}

button:hover {
  border: 6px solid crimson;
  font-weight: 800;
  background-color: white;
  color: crimson;
  margin: 0;
}
```

From [Stop an element moving with padding on hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20590246/stop-an-element-moving-with-padding-on-hover).

Comment: Thanks a lot. One question left: margin is 4px and border is 6px. => There's a difference of 2px left. Are does 2px the default border the button has already? So that we have only 4px instead of full 6px ...

Comment: No. It's actually a difference of 2px the other way, because the 4px sets both the top and bottom margins, giving 8px total of vertical margin. I initially tried 3px (6px total), but it was still shifting, so I bumped it up by 1px to prevent that.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I still think these inaccuracy might be caused by the browser's default CSS. After applying a reset it worked exact. Like expected. See my fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/hax1prjv/

Answer (score 9):

You need to define transparent border by default on `button` and change `border-color` on hover. Further avoid changing `font-weight` property on hover as well as it will also expand the width and height of button and it will jump on hover.

```css
body div:first-child {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  background-color: #dedede;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-left: 300px;
  width: 120px;
  height: 80px;
  border-radius: 8px;
}

button {
  border: 6px solid transparent;
  font-weight: 800;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}

button:hover {
  border-color: crimson;
  background-color: white;
  color: crimson;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <button>SUBMIT</button>
  <div>Please notice that ...</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Awesome answer, so simple I didn't even think of it

Answer (score 3):

Just to give an alternative you could use `outline` to set the "border" on hover.

```css
body div:first-child {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  background-color: #dedede;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-left: 300px;
  width: 120px;
  height: 80px;
  border-radius: 8px;
}
button {
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  margin: 5px 0;
}
button:hover {
  outline: 6px solid crimson;
  font-weight: 800;
  background-color: white;
  color: crimson;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <button>SUBMIT</button>
  <div>Please notice that ...</div>
</div>
```

Another option:

```css
body div:first-child {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  background-color: #dedede;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-left: 300px;
  width: 120px;
  height: 80px;
  border-radius: 8px;
}
button {
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  margin: 6px 0;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-style: outset;
  border-color: buttonface;
}
button:hover {
  border-width: 6px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: crimson;
  font-weight: 800;
  margin: 2px 0;
  background-color: white;
  color: crimson;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <button>SUBMIT</button>
  <div>Please notice that ...</div>
</div>
```

Comment: outline was the cleanest option

Answer (score 1):

Here are some possibilities:

1. Style the button dimensions (padding/margin/border) with the same px/em values like it's :hover state
2. set the button position to absolute/fixed
3. Use a fix height in a parent div

Comment: Possibility 1. is helpful. Possibilty 2. has side-effects on the following text.

Comment: Correct, 2 or 3 only works for fix size elements like icons on corner buttons

Answer (score 0):

check now

```css
body div:first-child {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  background-color: #dedede;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-left: 300px;
  width: 120px;
  height: 80px;
  border-radius: 8px;
}

button {
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
 border: 6px solid transparent;
}

button:hover {
  border: 6px solid crimson;
  font-weight: 800;
  background-color: white;
  color: crimson;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <button>SUBMIT</button>
  <div>Please notice that ...</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `height` to button

```css
body div:first-child {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  background-color: #dedede;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-left: 300px;
  width: 120px;
  height: 80px;
  border-radius: 8px;
}

button {
   border-radius: 4px;
   padding: 5px 10px;
   height:40px
}

button:hover {
  border: 6px solid crimson;
  font-weight: 800;
  background-color: white;
  color: crimson;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <button>SUBMIT</button>
  <div>Please notice that ...</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Mention the width and height to the button and remove the font-weight to avoiding a shifting of the element when hover the elements. Check below code.

```css
body div:first-child {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  background-color: #dedede;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-left: 300px;
  width: 120px;
  height: 80px;
  border-radius: 8px;
}

button {
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  height:50px;
  width:100px;
}

button:hover {
   /*font-weight: 800;
  background-color: white;*/
  border: 6px solid crimson;
  color: crimson;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <button>SUBMIT</button>
  
  <div>Please notice that ...</div>
</div>
```

```css
body div:first-child {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  background-color: #dedede;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-left: 300px;
  width: 120px;
  height: 80px;
  border-radius: 8px;
}

button {
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  height:50px;
  width:100px;
}

button:hover {
  border: 6px solid crimson;
  background-color: white;
  color: crimson;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <button>SUBMIT</button>
  <div>Please notice that ...</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add padding of the same size as the border to the button, and remove it on hover.